# Sample Facebook classes for c#?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Like some of you allready know, i'm trying to get data from facebook in JSON format and view it in a gridview or something like that.

With some help of StackOverflow, i managed to get the data i needed.

Now I want to make a List of my json string.
Do I have to make a class for every JSON object in my json string? Like the class user, location, work_info, education_info?

Is there any place where i can find the c# class files for all the facebook objects?

I think there are a lot of programers who use these classes, does everyone write the same classes again?

I have added a reference to the facebook(.web) sdk. But I don't know if I can use this for my problem.

I hope you can help me,

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why there are not strongly typed classes for Facebook Schema in the Facebook C# SDK is that they usually change very frecuently. That's why the developers of the Facebook C# SDK decided not to go that way:

- http://ntotten.com/2010/08/dynamic-csharp-with-frequently-changing-web-services/
- http://ntotten.com/2010/09/dynamic-objects-and-the-facebook-c-sdk/

Although if read the Roadmap: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Road%20Map you will see that there are plans for a strongly typed Graph API objects but it looks like there is no much activity in that area.

If you need strongly typed classes for your app, you will probably only use a few that are easy to create.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's not so much work to do it yourself as you said, but i could saved me some time, and other people too i guess. But thanks for your detailed respons!